# Replacing array element with specific elements from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to implement the merge sort using javascript and the problem I've ran into is that I can't replace my original array of numbers with values from the sorted sub-array(s).

I've seen the following solution in a similar question:

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var anotherArr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));

console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

However, here **ALL** the elements of `anotherArr` are being put into `arr`.

Is there a way for me to specify **only** the elements I want to insert into `arr` instead?

Comment: What's the output that you want?

Comment: The original array to be overwritten with elements from the sub-array. But only with the specified elements of that sub-array.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty please establish the unknowns, i.e. how will you describe _which_ specified elements of the subarray shall be used, and into which part of the original array.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty also, will those specified elements by contiguous, and will they replace the same number of elements in the destination array?

Comment: Imagine two sub-arrays, where each value within the same index are being compared. The smaller of the two values overwrites the value in the first position in the original index. Then the array counter increments, and the same operation keeps repeating until the array is exhausted.

And once the whole operation is done, yes, it will replace the same number of elements in the destination array.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you just want to overwrite the elements 1 and 3

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var anotherArr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var overwrite = [true, false, true];

for(var i = 0; i < anotherArr.length; i++){
    if(overwrite[i] == true) arr[i] = anotherArr[i];
}

alert(arr);
```

Output: `arr = [ '1', 'b', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];`

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarvady/yqh3f3vj/1/)

Comment: Hmm this works but in a very roundabout way and only when I specify one of the sub-array elements to be `null`. In my sub-array there aren't any `null` elements.

Comment: And if you use an auxiliar array how now?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you said. Could you elaborate a little? Thanks.

Comment: Look now the code. With the new array `var overwrite` you can indicate the elements that you want overwrite. You must put `true` or `false` on the positions

Comment: Interesting approach, but this will get really clumsy when you need to increment the index on the original array and overwrite more elements, say, under an if/else condition. 

Is there any array method that can help in approaching this problem  for a bigger array in a more straightforward way?

Comment: You must indicate the positions that you want replace anyway